# When I compile my code, I get an error of msgrcv: argument list too long for readmsg.c

Tags: c, unix

My code keeps giving an error of `msgrcv: argument list too long` for `readmsg.c`. Attached below is the full code.

#### readmsg.c

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <sys/shm.h>
   #include <fcntl.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <errno.h>
   #include <sys/msg.h>
   typedef struct msgp{
          long type;
          char data[64];
  }msgp_t;
  
  int main(void){
          key_t key = ftok(".",123);
          if(key == -1){
                  perror("ftok");
                  return -1;
          }
          printf("%dprocess: accessing the existing linked list\n",getpid());
          int msgid = msgget(key,0);
          if(msgid == -1){
                  perror("msgget");
                  return -1;
          }
          printf("%dprocess: receiving messages from misgid %d.\n",getpid(),msgid);
          for(;;){
                  msgp_t buf={};
                  //using msgid, and -1 bc of the fgets function and a 0 so that it is pending f    unction. 
                  ssize_t size = msgrcv(msgid,&buf,sizeof(buf.data)-1,1234,0);
                  if(size == -1){
                          if(errno==EIDRM){
                                  printf("No more messages\n");
                                  break;
                          }
                          else perror("msgcrcv");
                          return -1;
                  }
                  printf("%ld>>%s",buf.type,buf.data);
          }
          printf("%dprocess: task completed!\n",getpid());
          return 0;
  }
```

#### msg.c

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <sys/shm.h>
   #include <fcntl.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <sys/msg.h>
   typedef struct msgp{
           long type;
          char data[64];
  }msgp_t;
  
  int main(void){
          printf("%dprocess:creating key\n",getpid());
          key_t key = ftok(".",123);
          if(key == -1){
                  perror("ftok");
                  return -1;
          }
          printf("%dprocess: creating a linked list\n",getpid());
          int msgid= msgget(key,IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0664);
          if(msgid ==-1){
                  perror("msgget");
                  return -1;
          }
          for(;;){
                  msgp_t buf={1234};
                  fgets(buf.data, sizeof(buf.data),stdin);
                  if(strcmp(buf.data,"!\n")==0){
                          break;
          }
                  if(msgsnd(msgid,&buf,sizeof(buf.data),0)==-1){
                          perror("msgsnd");
                          return -1;
                  }
          }
          printf("%dprocess: clearing the linked list\n",getpid());
          if (msgctl(msgid, IPC_RMID,NULL)==-1){
                  perror("msgctl");
                  return -1;
          }
          printf("%dprocess: task completed!\n",getpid());
          return 0;
  }
```

I am not sure why msgcrv is giving this problem. I checked the manual for the arguments, and it was correct. :( Other parts of the code are working correctly. I'm quite new to C, so it would be great if you could provide some valuable suggestions!

Comment: Your opening comment says `msgprcv` but I see no such identifier in the code.  Typo in the question?

Comment: Hello yup it is a typo. The problem lies in msgrcv in readmsg.c!

Comment: _"My code keeps giving an error"_ - It's a compilation error, right? How do you compile it?

Comment: @WinnieWang You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76551305/edit) the question to correct the typos

Comment: You should be using a header to declare `msgp_t` and including that header in the two files.  That ensures that type definition is consistent — a key feature of headers.

Comment: CNR — Cannot Reproduce.  Taking the code in `readmsg.c`, the code compiles cleanly for me on macOS Monterey 12.6.7.  It has some extraneous headers (which I removed — it only needs `<errno.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<sys/msg.h>`, `<unistd.h>`) but those should not be a factor.  I'm compiling using Clang disguised as GCC with the command line `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common -c msg83.c` (renamed source file).

Comment: Similar comments apply to `msg.c` — it compiles cleanly in my environment.

Comment: Hello! I realised the reason is because I needed to give buf[65] instead of buf[64 ] in readmsg.c for msgp . (My guess is because fgets takes in \n as one char also) TQSM for your help!